# How do I copy Opera Mini browser cookies?

Tags: opera-mini

Is there a way to copy the Opera Mini's cookies from one phone to another? (same model of phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rooted, you could use an app such as [MyBackup Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupRoot) or [Titanum Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to backup Opera Mini, and then restore it on the new device.

It is not possible if you're not rooted.